# How to remove leading Plus sign inside parentheses

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I am trying to modify (beautify) an expression in a file; it looks as follows (example only):

```
exp = Z1*( + A1 + B1 + C1 ) + ( - A2 + A1 + B2 ) - ( + K + C );
```

where the leading '+' signs inside parentheses are unwanted. 
Is there a way to remove them?

The expected output is

```
exp = Z1*( A1 + B1 + C1 ) + ( - A2 + A1 + B2 ) - ( K + C );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ sed 's/( *+/(/g' file
exp = Z1*( A1 + B1 + C1 ) + ( - A2 + A1 + B2 ) - ( K + C );
```